# Datacenter traffic reporting with Cacti

Tags: networking, snmp

I am trying to get a good profile of my data usage so I know what kind of connection speeds I need when placing servers for colocation.

I have Cacti installed and connected to 2 servers through snmp so far. I am trying to get the following data sources available on my tree:

```
Interface - Traffic (bits/sec)      
Interface - Traffic (bits/sec, 95th Percentile)         
Interface - Traffic (bits/sec, Total Bandwidth)         
Interface - Traffic (bytes/sec)     
Interface - Traffic (bytes/sec, Total Bandwidth)
```

Under devices I have the servers setup as `Generic SNMP-enabled Host` using version 1 snmp. The only `Associated Graph Templates` currently assigned are:

```
1) Linux - Memory Usage 
2) ucd/net - Load Average
3) Unix - Load Average
```

When I go to add more, the only available options are:

```
Cisco - CPU Usage               
Host MIB - Logged in Users      
Host MIB - Processes            
Linux - Memory Usage            
Netware - File System Activity  
Netware - File System Cache     
Netware - Logged In Users       
Netware - Open Files            
SNMP - Generic OID Template     
ucd/net - CPU Usage              
ucd/net - Load Average          
ucd/net - Memory Usage          
Unix - Load Average              
Unix - Logged in Users          
Unix - Ping Latency              
Unix - Processes
```

There are a lot of great templates I would love to use, but not sure why I can't access them on the drop down. When looking under the `Host Templates` section, there doesn't seem to be anything there that details which templates should be available to which kind of host nor do I see anything under the `Graph Templates` section.

I have about 10 Ubuntu and CentOS servers I would like to be able to monitor, what am I missing to enable the other templates?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone that needs to know, the thing to do is 1st make sure on the "Device" page at the bottom make sure "SNMP - Interface Statistics" is there under "Associated Data Queries".

At the top of the page, click "Create Graphs for this Host" and select the interface you want, and select the graph type.

Next under Graph Trees, you should be able to add your graph where you want. Sometimes I end up with an empty graph, and sometimes it works, I haven't troubleshot it enough and ended up switching to Zabbix but if anyone wants to comment on the empty graphs they can and I will test it.